# TDengine Grafana datasource plugin error in Grafana 5

Tags: grafana, tdengine

TDengine datasource plugin for Grafana 3.1.3 is not valid in Grafana 5.4.3 . Although we know that it's ok in latest versions of Grafana, we have some private reasons to stay with this specific version.

When adding a TDengine datasource, Grafana shows **HTTP Error Not Found** error message. We can see the url causing 404 like below:

[image: 404 not found while adding data source]

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to [v4.1.4](https://github.com/taosdata/grafanaplugin/releases/tag/v3.1.4), everything will be ok except builtin sms alert.